# how can i use url encode Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, urlencode

i am working in a project and want use the name of a post as URL, then i did this:

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/{nombre}',['as' => 'noticias.show', 'uses' => 'NoticiasController@show'])->where('nombre', '[A-Za-z0-9-_]+');
```

and i did this:

**Contoller.php**

```
public function show($nombre)
    {
        $Noticia = Noticias::where('nombre', $nombre)->first();
        $Categorias = categoriasn::CategoriaN();
        if(!$Noticia){
            return 'No exite ninguna noticia';
        }
        return view('noticias.noticia')->with(compact('Noticia'))->with(compact('Categorias'));
    }
```

this is the way i use to call a post, using `name`, but for example if the post has a space the url show me `%20, and no display the post.

if someone can help will be awesome.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hint

Instead of passing `post name` of every post, you may use `post-slug`.

1. You can add a extra column on database posts table called `post-slug`.
2. Prepare every post name to `post-slug` by removing space and a replace dash(-) while saving post.